# Rails failing to parse Accept header when charset given

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, character-encoding, http-headers

When hitting an API in a Rails app, it seems that certain headers fail to be parsed. For example, this works:

```
Accept: application/json
```

But this doesn't:

```
Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Is failing to understand this 2nd header a legitimate problem with the header? Even if it is, how can I make Rails understand it, or at least understand that it's a request for Json?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that, in Rails 3.2.14, the [Mime::Type.parse](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.14/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb#L110) method does not support specifying a charset parameter in the Accept header; in fact it only supports the "q" parameter (see the [Q_SEPARATOR_REGEXP](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.14/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb#L85) constant).

In Rails 4, however, the method has been updated to support arbitrary parameters (see [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8c4b3a4dea79e949da583b379714a2cc4bf92ab4)), so upgrading to Rails 4 should fix this problem.

If you can't upgrade to Rails 4, I would suggest doing a temporary hack in some Rack middleware to strip out the charset (this assumes you don't actually intend to honour the acceptable charset):

```
class AcceptCharsetStripper
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    env["HTTP_ACCEPT"].gsub!(/;\s*charset=\S+/, "")
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```